# Manipulate active tab in angular

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

setAlas, another angular question - it just doesn't work as intuitively as I hoped.

In `templates` I have a couple tabs:

```
<div ng-init="setActiveTab(1)" class="tab-nav two-tabs clear">
    <div ng-class="{active:tab===1}" ng-click="tab = 1">
        Tab 1
    </div>

    <div ng-class="{active:tab===2}" ng-click="tab = 2">
        Tab 2
    </div>
</div>
```

These toggle content:

```
<div class="content" ng-show="tab === 1">
    Foo
</div>

<div class="content" ng-show="tab === 2">
    Bar
</div>
```

In the corresponding `controller` I have the `setActiveTab()` function:

```
$scope.setActiveTab = function(tab)
{
    return 'tab = '+tab;
};
```

Pretty straight forward right? Well not really, it completely ignores the function. When I manually type in `tab = 1` into `ng-init` it magically works - seriously what is going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

make tab a $scope variable

try

```
$scope.setActiveTab = function(val) {
    $scope.tab = val;
}


<div ng-init="setActiveTab(1)" class="tab-nav two-tabs clear">
    <div ng-class="{active:tab===1}" ng-click="setActiveTab(1)">
        Tab 1
    </div>

    <div ng-class="{active:tab===2}" ng-click="setActiveTab(2)">
        Tab 2
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank-you - I hate that it worked, silly angular - or rather, silly me.

Comment: yeah basically the dom had no idea what tab was since it wasnt declared as a scope variable in your controller. glad it worked!